# Issues with Network connectivity with Docker

Tags: docker

I am facing issues configuring network in docker. Details are given below.

Host Machine:- Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS 64-bit. IP subnet: 10.0.0.0/16, IP address: 10.0.0.206/16 and default gateway: 10.0.0.1/16. This machine having docker installed (version 1.6.2 build 7c8fca2) and has a default IP in the docker0 bridge of 172.17.42.1/16. However, the container has received the IP as 172.17.0.1. Problems are as follows.

1. My Host machine and docker container is able to connect with each other and to Internet but any other machines are not able to connect with docker container.
2. Changing the docker0 bridge IP is temporary and reverts back to 172.17.42.1/16 once every reboot.
3. I cannot set a static IP address of my container as it changes automatically at every exit or if the host is rebooted. Checked the container's network config file /etc/network/interfaces but doing changes in this file has no effect to its eth0 interface.

In very short, I am not able to connect to the container from outer world (from other physical machines) even when I have configured the networking interface of other machines to connect to docker host and container.

How can I fix this connection problem?

Comment: what's protocol and port do you want to connect from outside to docker container ? how did you run container ? `docker run -d -p xx:xx image`

Comment: First question that comes to my mind: why are you running a fairly out of date version of Docker? I say that just in case there is some other issue that is giving you problems. Be warned that they changed the IPs for docker0 in 1.9 (I believe). Also, I recall that setting a static IP address in a container is an anti-pattern, but if you must, then you have to make sure you _docker commit_ that information or it will be gone every time you restart the container.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Docker containers can not be accessed from other host. And the IP address is allocated by docker.

You can use "--net=host" when run containers, then the container will share the same IP address with the host node. And the container will be available from other node.

```
docker run -it --net=host ubuntu bash
```